# How to add Cancel button to Batch operation?

Tags: 7, batch-operations

How to add Cancel button to Batch operation?
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to interrupt a batch process, afaik. There used to be a hackish trick in Drupal 6 though, see http://drupal.org/node/894222. Maybe if you can figure out how that worked, you can make Drupal 7 do the same.

Answer (score -3):

Define your operation like this:

```
$batch = array(
  'title' => t('Exporting'),
  'operations' => array(
    array('my_function_1', array($account->uid, 'story')),
    array('my_function_2', array()),
  ),
  'finished' => 'my_finished_callback',
  'file' => 'path_to_file_containing_myfunctions',
);
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/batch/7

Comment: That doesn't add a cancel button, it's just a standard batch definition